# Set an upper bound of a pyomo constraint

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

Suppose I have a pyomo constraint `con1` of the form:

```
    from pyomo.environ import *
    model = ConcreteModel()
    model.x_1 = Var()
    model.x_2 = Var()
    model.con1 = Constraint(expr=-exp(model.x_1) -  model.x_2 <= 0)
```

I want to manipulate the upper bound (in general the right hand side) of `model.c1`, i.e. subtract some value `c`.

I can query the upper (lower) bound by using the `.upper()` (`.lower()`)-method and I found that

```
    model.con1.set_value(model.con1.body <= model.con1.upper()-c)
```

seems to work for `<=`-restrictions and that

```
    model.con1.set_value(model.con1.body >= model.con1.lower()-c)
```

seems to work for `>=`-restrictions.

Does my approach have potential side-effects (which I am currently unaware of)? Is there a more elegant way of manipulating the right hand side of a constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to use a mutable parameter:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
m = ConcreteModel()
m.p_ub = Param(initialize=10, mutable=True)
m.x1 = Var()
m.con1 = Constraint(expr=m.x1 <= m.p_ub)
```

Then if you want to change the value of the upper bound you can do something like:

```
m.p_ub = value(m.p_ub)-c
```

Just remember that you cannot use a Pyomo Variable as an upper or lower bound, they must be numeric constants.